# Constraining associated types in Swift protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I'm writing a little code snippet to learn about how associated types work, but I've come across an error I'm not sure how to interpret. The code I've written is posted below for reference.

```
// A basic protocol
protocol Doable {
    func doSomething() -> Bool
}

// An extension that adds a method to arrays containing Doables
extension Array where Element: Doable {

    func modify(using function:(Array<Doable>)->Array<Doable>) -> Array<Doable> {
        return function(self)
    }
}

// Another protocol with an associated type constrained to be Doable
protocol MyProtocol {
    associatedtype MyType: Doable

    func doers() -> Array<MyType>

    func change(_:Array<MyType>) -> Array<MyType>
}

// An simple extension
extension MyProtocol {

    func modifyDoers() -> Array<MyType> {
        return doers().modify(using: change)
    }
}
```

I've constrained `MyType` to be `Doable`, but the compiler complains that it cannot convert `(Array<Self.MyType>) -> Array<Self.MyType> to expected argument type (Array<Doable>) -> Array<Doable>`. Can anybody explain what's going on here and how I can make the compiler happy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, the `modify` function expects arguments with the type `Array<Doable>` and you're passing arguments with the type `Array<MyType>`.

The issue stems from the definition of `modify`, where you're explicitly using `Doable` in the parameters, which excludes all other types but `Doable` – and as associated types are not typealiases, `MyType` can't be converted to `Doable`.

The fix is to change all occurrences of `Doable` in the `modify` function to `Element`, as is portrayed in the Swift documentation: [Extensions with a Generic Where Clause](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Generics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH26-ID553).

Comment: Excellent explanation. Thanks for the link too. This is why I love SO.